# Spring intercept http request for authorization endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, interceptor

I need a callback before http request on `/oauth/authorize`, I tried using the standard interceptor pattern on `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` like follows:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new UserAuthorizationInterceptor())
            .addPathPatterns("/oauth/authorize");
    }

// .... 

private class UserAuthorizationInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(); // breakpoint
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(); // breakpoint
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        return true; // breakpoint
    }
```

This for some reason does not trigger for any pattern that's `/oauth/**`, however if I would replace the path matcher with something like `.addPathPatterns("/**");` it would still trigger on most http request **EXCEPT** anything that starts with `oauth`. How can I implement this handler?

**EDIT**

I tried solving this with global filter approach

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class Foo implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request,response); // breakpoint
    }

}
```

However again, this filter is called for every http request **EXCEPT** `/oauth/**`. It seems to me that oauth requests are simply not passed down to the filter  chain

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an interceptor through the Spring Security [AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter.html):

```
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints.addInterceptor(new CustomInterceptor());
  }

  private class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, @Nullable Exception ex) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

This way, you can add either an [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) or an [WebRequestInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequestInterceptor.html), or even both if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have a `.excludePathPatterns("/oauth/**")` somewhere downstrean, since you cannot access it with `UserAuthorizationInterceptor` when `.addPathPatterns("/**");`

Comment: No, nothing like that.